# Frequency of given voltage

Tags: frequency

I need help with this task if anyone had a similar problem it would help me a lot?

The task is:

The waveform of simple periodic voltage is observed, where the time distance between adjacent maximum and minimum values $$(U_{max},U_{min})$$ ​​is equal to 5ms. What is the frequency of a given voltage?

I tried this:

$$T=\frac{1}{f}\\f=\frac{1}{T}\\f=\frac{1}{5\cdot 10^{-3}}=200Hz$$

But, correct answer is $$f=100Hz$$

Thanks in advance!
Best regards !

Comment: You have to actually read the question. You can't just pick out keywords and numbers and go with it. It never said the period is 5ms.

Comment: Or draw a sine wave (as an example) and mark the `5ms` between a peak and a valley.

Comment: Frequency can be thought of as the rate of **repetitions**.  So, you should consider the time distance between the two points where the voltage values are **repeated**. If you draw the waveform (could be either square/rectangular pulses or sinewave) then you'll understand better what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have been given the time difference between the maximum and minimum value of the signal. Have a look below:

[image]

Can you see where you are going wrong?

Comment: Yeah, T=10ms...Thank you a lot !

Comment: Please don't give out solutions to homework questions. Note how the comments have tried to lead the OP to answering this question themselves.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I merely pointed out a flaw in OP’s thinking. I didn’t give OP the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Understood you have simple waveform that has Umax to Umin = 5ms
Period of any simple wave form is MAX to MAX or MIN TO MIN or zero crossing going up to zero crossing going up or zero crossing going down to zero crossing going down.

so it means if it is simple that Umax to Umin = 5ms also Umin to Umax should be = 5ms

If period is Umax to Umax that means T is 10ms or f=100Hz

Comment: Thank you a lot !

Comment: Please don't give out solutions to homework questions. Note how the comments have tried to lead the OP to answering this question themselves.